# Rebind of data-ng-click not working

Tags: angularjs

I am using this template and binding data with it

```
<div id="groupSegment" data-ng-repeat="q in CurrentQuestion">
    Segment Info
   <div>{{q.SegmentName}}</div>
    Questions:
         <div>{{q.Title}}</div><div>{{q.Description}}</div>
    <input  type="button" value="Previous" id="d{{q.PrevQuestIndex}}"  data-ng-click="ChangeQuestion({{q.PrevQuestIndex}})" /><br /> <input  id="d{{q.NextQuestIndex}}"  type="button" value="Next" data-ng-click="ChangeQuestion({{q.NextQuestIndex}})" />
</div>
```

Issue coming that on click of Next and Previous its not updating the value of index when clicking next time. 
Html shows that the updated value is there but when i am clicking then its showing the value that was set when html renderd

Here is the funtion that firing on click.

```
$scope.ChangeQuestion = function (index) {//this indux value not getting changed
                if (index < 0 || index > $scope.Questions.length)
                    return;
                $scope.CurrentQuestion = [];
                var i = 0;
                $($scope.Questions[index]).each(function () {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        $scope.CurrentQuestion.push({  Title: this.Title, Description: this.Description,SegmentName: this.SegmentName, NextQuestIndex: index + 1, PrevQuestIndex: index - 1 });
                    }
                    i++
                });
                $scope.$apply();
            };
```

So how I can refresh this on click parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I'm using  **ng-click** instead of  **data-ng-click** which you used..
Also You don't need to pass parameters with `{{}}` if you use it inside **ng-** tag.

Change it as **ng-click="ChangeQuestion(q.PrevQuestIndex)"**

```html
<div id="groupSegment" data-ng-repeat="q in CurrentQuestion">
    Segment Info
   <div>{{q.SegmentName}}</div>
    Questions:
         <div>{{q.Title}}</div><div>{{q.Description}}</div>
    <input  type="button" value="Previous" id="d{{q.PrevQuestIndex}}"  ng-click="ChangeQuestion(q.PrevQuestIndex)" /><br /> 
    <input  id="d{{q.NextQuestIndex}}"  type="button" value="Next" ng-click="ChangeQuestion(q.NextQuestIndex)" />
</div>
```